# How to provide power from Android to external device?

Tags: android, permissions, command, hardware

I have [Android 8.0 device based on Snapdragon 626](https://spectrageospatial.com/mobilemapper-60/), which isn't rooted. Documentation of my device has an info, that if I use command:

```
/sys/class/ext_dev/function/ext_dev_5v_enable
```

with output `1` I should be able to enable 5V power supply output on dedicated hardware port in my device. If I use output `0` I should be able to disable it.

Similar command

```
/sys/class/ext_dev/function/ext_dev_3v3_enable
```

could do the same for 3.3V power output.

Both of power supply ports are turned off by default.

I paste above commands into console on Android and get exception "not found":

[image]

Probably command line app doesn't have necessary permission from OS to get access to this hardware port, but I'm writing my own app and I have to provide power to external device using my app.

About which one permission should I ask Android to get access to those ports using above commands? Maybe something else cause this issue?

Comment: You need to specify the exact device (Make and Model) you are using as this is probably very specific to that Android device,

Comment: I updated main post with details of my device and link to manufacturer's product page.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little detail on the Pogo pin connectors this device has BUT it looks very much like similar devices which have more details with code e.g. https://www.handheldgroup.com/knowledge-base/algiz-rt8-back-docking-connector/

Looking at the JNI of the library these look like file like devices NOT scripts to run.

You could try and confirm they are file like devices by listing them e.g.
`ls -la /sys/class/ext_dev/function/` or `file /sys/class/ext_dev/function/ext_dev_5v_enable`

So to replicate how the JNI library uses these type of devices from the command line as you would do in linux (what Android is based on)

To write enabled
`echo 1 > /sys/class/ext_dev/function/ext_dev_5v_enable`

To read value
`cat /sys/class/ext_dev/function/ext_dev_5v_enable`

Note I have no experience with these particular devices, so no guarantees this will work.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I will check this and back with answer whether it helps.